# I get ValueError with the ndim when I run model.predict(X)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, python-3.7, tensorflow2.0

I use this code to train my model on my data

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
tf.random.set_seed(50)
np.random.seed(50)
train_set = windowed_dataset(x_train, window_size=30, batch_size=15, shuffle_buffer=shuffle_buffer_size)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=100, kernel_size=5,
                      strides=1, padding="causal",
                      activation="relu",
                      input_shape=[None, 1]),
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, return_sequences=True),
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100, return_sequences=True),
  #tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation="relu"),
  #tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation="relu"),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
  tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x * 400)
])


optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
    learning_rate=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07, amsgrad=True,
    name='Adam'
)
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.Huber(),
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=["mae"])
history = model.fit(train_set,epochs=100)
```

here is the model.summary()

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, 30, 100)           600       
_________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 30, 100)           80400     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 30, 100)           80400     
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 30, 1)             101       
_________________________________________________________________
lambda (Lambda)              (None, 30, 1)             0         
=================================================================
Total params: 161,501
Trainable params: 161,501
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

I am trying to run this code

```
model.predict(
    x_valid, batch_size=None, verbose=0, steps=None, callbacks=None, max_queue_size=10,
    workers=1, use_multiprocessing=False
)
```

and it throws back this error message:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the
>   layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 1]

I tried reshaping x_valid with this function `np.array(x_valid).reshape(300,1)`, but that didn't work .

I have solved the issue by expanding the ndim three times

```
    test_input = x_valid[425]
    test_input = np.expand_dims(test_input,axis=0)
    test_input = np.expand_dims(test_input,axis=0)
    test_input = np.expand_dims(test_input,axis=0)

    print(model.predict(test_input))
    # OUTPUT [[[71.46894]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promblem comes from the incorrect test data dimentionality. The x_input has shape (15,30,1) so from this comes up that the test data must also have 3-dim shape (ex. [1,1,1]). In your code test data is a 1-dim array so you should expand dims TWICE to reach 3-dim array using 'test_input = np.expand_dims(test_input,axis=0)'

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the fact that you need to add the batch_dimension in order to predict on one datapoint.

This is necessary when dealing with TensorFlow and Keras, even if you predict on one single sample, you need to add batch_size of 1.

What you need to do is:

1. Fetch one item from your test set (say, `test_input = x_valid[0]`)
2. Construct the batch_size of 1, i.e. `test_input = np.expand_dims(test_input,axis=0)`
3. Now predict with the model, i.e. `prediction = model.predict(test_input)`

Comment: I did your instructions above and, unfortunately, got this error "    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 1]"